# How to use Certreq to generate CSR and install on Windows VM with no IIS Mgr?

Tags: ssl, iis, ssl-certificate, virtual-machines, windows-server-2016

I am running an Azure Windows VM. I used Certreq to create a CSR file using the following command:

`certreq.exe -new request.inf nctest.csr`

It all looks good. I have to pass the csr file off to a client who is then going to get the SSL from the domain registrar. I then need to get SSL up and running on the VM with the provided certificates.

It appears that I just need to run the command:

`certreq -accept example.com.crt`

And I'm good to go? I'm assuming I can use this as next steps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25290387/139196

However, I'm also unsure where to get the SSL certificate password mentioned here:

`$mypwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "SSLCertificate password" -Force –AsPlainText`

Can I ignore and just not pass a password if none was provided as part of the creation using Certreq?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, I'm also unsure where to get the SSL certificate password mentioned here:

you don't need the password. You already have installed the certificate so this and next script line (Import-PfxCertificate cmdlet call) must be omitted.

Comment: Thanks. So, I'm guessing the "certreq -accept" command is doing something similar to what Import-PfxCertificate does.

Comment: Similar in terms of result, yes.